# Why won't photos import from iPhone after upgrade?

Tags: iphone, photos.app, catalina

Since upgrading to Catalina I can no longer import photos from my iPhone into the Photos app.

I can drag photos from my desktop into the library, but clicking either "Import selected" or "Import all new items" from the device menu fails to work. No error messages. In fact it shows the circular progress meter, then nothing. Photos not imported.

Important to note is that my .photoslibrary directory is on a **network drive** over AFP. Despite being rather slow, this has always worked in the past and still works for all other functions.

I tested a local library on the startup disk and photos **can** be imported, so I suspect the network drive is the issue.

I have the same problem syncing albums to iPhone from libraries on network drives. Again, syncing from a locally stored library works fine.

Any idea how I can fix this issue?